# Overwrite Android Application

Tags: android, android-manifest, overwrite

I'd like to overwrite my old android application. What are the things  i have to be  do for that ?

Do Changes in `AndroidManifest.xml` is enough ?
I like to use another package structure and a new project to do so.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following are required:

1. Same key
2. Same Package Name
3. Higher versionCode in the manifest

Comment: same package mean that; let's say the old one is.

com.xyz.qwd

then the new one needs to be same ?

Answer (score 2):

The package name indicated in the manifest should be the same:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.company.demo.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the registration in Google Play, I think that only the `package="..."` attribute of the `<manifest>` node must be the same (and the version must be superior to the one of your first application of course).

It must also be signed with the same key.

That way, the Google Play site will recognize your old application as a new version, and it will replace the old one.